# PHP Listing objects from a folder in a S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 Bucket, inside I have a bunch of folders.
When I list the objects from one of the folders, for example `folder1`, I get all the item but I also get the name of the folder listed too.
I have tried using a **delimiter**, or a **KeyMarker** but It seems like it is not responding well.

I am using this code which lists all the objects, but also the folder name on which those objects are from.

```
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        "Bucket" => $bucket,
        "Prefix" => 'folder1/',
        'KeyMarker' => 'folder1/', //don't list folder1/ and start listing after this folder.
    )); 
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo "<li><strong>" . basename($object['Key']) . "</strong> Size: " . $object['Size'] .  " bytes  ";
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I am adding the output from the code above:

```
folder1 Size: 0 bytes
test.txt Size: 250 bytes
johnpdf.pdf Size: 422 bytes
```

Desired output:

```
test.txt Size: 250 bytes
johnpdf.pdf Size: 422 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to implement was.

```
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
        "Bucket" => $bucket,
        'Marker' => 'folder1/',
        "Prefix" => "folder1/"


        
    )); 
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo "<li><strong>" . $object['Key'] . "</strong> Size: " . $object['Size'] .  " bytes  ";
    }
```